# Windows won't boot into BIOS

Tags: windows, display, bios

Not sure what I did but Windows completely skips the BIOS screen and goes straight to login. I didn't turn on fast boot either. I've tried unplugging my secondary monitor and rebooting with only my main but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Windows doesn't skip the BIOS screen but you may have changed a setting within the BIOS to not show it. Try repeatedly pressing whatever button you use to enter the BIOS after powering your PC on. It may be F2, F10 or the Del key.

Comment: One of the options if none of the keys work - detach the hard drive and this will let you to BIOS where you can check the boot options, including fast boot.